# How do I Import Encoding class to C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
static byte[] GetData()
{
string s = "this is some text";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
return data;
}
```

I found this code useful but I got an issue with GetData() method. after compiling the code I get message saying..

> Error: The name `Encoding' does not exist in the current context.

so how do I Import Encoding class to C# script?

Answer (score 8):

You have two options:

1. Import the namespace at the top of the script file:

   ```
   using System.Text;
   ```
2. Use fully qualified class name:

   ```
   byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
   ```